# NSOperationQueue setSuspended:NO not starting queue, NSLog does

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I've got a non-concurrent NSOperation running, which has a part in which a lot of network calls are made and the results processed. This seemed like an easy target for parallelization, so I did the following:

```
NSOperationQueue *downloadOperationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
downloadOperationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 5;

self.operationThread = [NSThread currentThread];
//prevent the operation queue from starting until we're ready to receive events
[downloadOperationQueue setSuspended:YES];

for (FooInfo *fooInfo in foos)
{
    //FooDownloadOperation is a non-concurrent operation.
    FooDownloadOperation *downloadOp = [[FooDownloadOperation alloc] initWithFoo:fooInfo];
    downloadOp.delegate = self;
    [downloadOperationQueue addOperation:downloadOp];
}
//unsuspend the queue and spin a run loop until the local operation count hits zero
[downloadOperationQueue setSuspended:NO];
while (self.isCancelled == NO && [downloadOperationQueue operationCount] > 0) 
{
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1.0f]];
}
// ... do other things
```

and there's another method that -main in FooDownloadOperation calls, which does a performSelector:onThread: to jump back to self.operationThread to process the results:

```
- (void)downloadOperation:(FooDownloadOperation *)downloadOp didSucceed:(NSArray *)results
{
    if ([[NSThread currentThread] isEqual:self.operationThread] == NO)
    {
        //too many arguments for -performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:
        NSInvocation *inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[self methodSignatureForSelector:_cmd]];
        [inv setTarget:self];
        [inv setSelector:_cmd];
        [inv setArgument:&downloadOp atIndex:2];
        [inv setArgument:&results atIndex:3];
        [inv retainArguments];
        [inv performSelector:@selector(invoke) onThread:self.operationThread withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
        return;
    }

    //... process the results
}
```

No problem. In theory.

In fact, about 70% of the time, worse after waking the device up from sleep and running the operation, it just sits in the while loop, -runMode:untilDate: returning NO. Strangely, after anywhere from 20 seconds to 6 minutes, the FooDownloadOperations finally start.

To make matters more bizarre, if I add logging inside the while loop, it starts working as expected. I could just add some logging, but I'd really rather know why that seems to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your mixing metaphors so to speak. If your NSOpeations are not concurrent you don't have to worry about a runloop - you cannot message them while they run (if you need that feature, you need concurrent operations and should look on github for a number of examples on how to use those).

So, you don't need to know the current thread (which is the current thread of your main app, not the operations (in your code). So you create a queue, you suspend it, you add a whole bunch of operations to run, then when you want you tell the queue to run. You can then wait on the queue to complete, or you can poll it, etc.

Comment: I realize that I'm mixing metaphors. I want the parent operation to be message-able, by these FooDownloadOperations, only during this one time span. Making the parent operation concurrent (unless that's the reason this isn't working as I'd expect) is more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Right - you cannot message a non-concurrent operation. That's the primary reason for concurrent operations. BTW there is a really easy to use concurrent operations project (you use two files) on github -  NSOperation-WebFetches-MadeEasy